# How to make a graph of this function

Tags: functions

[image]

its just a game function from the wiki, but i cannot make any graphs. I need the number of rounds from 0 to 50, but dont evem know what should i enter in constructor sites.

Starting spawn level is unnecessary, can be just 1

Comment: Please refrain from using pictures. There are [different reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/1273570) for that, for example, the search function doesn’t see them. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead. The text is not that large to replicate it.

Comment: From your definition, $L(x)$ does not depend on $x$?

Comment: @Anne Bauval $L(x)$ is dependent on Round Number.

Comment: @Nesha, can you describe which constants and information you have?

Comment: @LucienJaccon look at the OP's$$\sum_{x=1}^{\text{Round Number}}L(x).$$ Better let Nesha clarify.